# Using Rvalue references and Simple Factory

Tags: c++, factory-method

I recently learnt about `std::move` and `rvalue` references, and want to know if my usage of them is both appropriate and efficient.

Consider this simple `Image` class which simply stores an array of `unsigned char` values representing pixels. (Note that in reality there are more members than a single array of chars but I simplify here for readability.)

```
using PixelContainer = std::vector<unsigned char>;

class Image {
public:
    Image(PixelContainer&& pixels) : m_pixels(std::move(pixels)) {};

    Image& operator=(Image&& image) { m_pixels = std::move(image.m_pixels); return *this; };

private:
    PixelContainer m_pixels;
};
```

And now consider this static method of an `ImageFactory` class which takes in a filename of a `.png` and returns an `Image` object filled with the appropriate pixel values.

```
Image ImageFactory::loadImage(const char* filename) {
    PixelContainer temp_pixels;

    // ... fill pixels from file (details not relevant here)

    Image temp_image(std::move(temp_pixels));

    return temp_image;
}
```

Finally, together they are used in code as such:

```
Image image = ImageFactory::loadImage("image.png");
```

I'm using `rvalue` references to presumably get rid of any time spent making copies of what can potentially be a large array of pixel values. Because the vector and image created by the factory are temporary, they can be moved around.

My question is, does my implementation make sense, and if it's not fundamentally flawed, can it be further improved?

Comment: Sorry I have to vote to close. Personally I think you are doing it correctly. BUT you will get a much better response if you ask on SO rather than codereview.

Comment: If a mod agrees with you and would like to migrate this to SO that is completely fine with me; I simply want a good answer, of course.

Comment: The general rule is to define both copy/move constructor and assignment operator simultaneously. Other than that I don't see any evident problem. I guess users of your class expect that there's no real _copy_ constructor, doesn't they?

Comment: @user3159253 That is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's find out!  I added a function like this to contain your final bit of code:

```
Image outer() {
    Image image = ImageFactory::loadImage("image.png");
    return image;
}
```

I also had to add a regular copy constructor for `Image` (I used `= default` to define it), because even if it isn't actually used, it is required to return-by-value.

I then compiled with Clang -O2 -g -S, and looked at the assembly.  It's mostly code to initialize the vector: call `operator new` and setup the vector's internal pointers.  There's no copying, the code looks reasonably clean and efficient.  And as you might hope, the code for `outer()` is nearly identical to the code for `loadImage()` (the latter is inlined into the former because I put everything in one translation unit).

For reference, here's the assembly I got:

```
outer():                             ## @_Z5outerv
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    pushq   %rbx
    pushq   %rax
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    movl    $100000000, %edi        ## imm = 0x5F5E100
    callq   operator new(unsigned long)
    movd    %rax, %xmm0
    movlhps %xmm0, %xmm0            ## xmm0 = xmm0[0,0]
    movq    $-100000000, %rcx       ## imm = 0xFFFFFFFFFA0A1F00
    movq    %rax, %rsi
LBB1_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    testq   %rsi, %rsi
    movl    $0, %edx
    je      LBB1_3
    movb    $0, (%rsi)
    movaps  %xmm0, %xmm1
    punpckhqdq      %xmm1, %xmm1    ## xmm1 = xmm1[1,1]
    movd    %xmm1, %rdx
LBB1_3:                                 ## %_ZNSt3__116allocator_traits...
    incq    %rdx
    movd    %rdx, %xmm1
    punpcklqdq      %xmm1, %xmm0    ## xmm0 = xmm0[0],xmm1[0]
    incq    %rcx
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    jne     LBB1_1
## BB#4:                                ## %_ZN12ImageFactory9loadImageEPKc.exit
    leaq    100000000(%rax), %rax
    movdqu  %xmm0, (%rbx)
    movq    %rax, 16(%rbx)
    movq    %rbx, %rax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```